# Is setting up private server for websites faster?

Tags: web-hosting

I am a web developer and my last website was a tad slower because of HD pictures, PHP and JQuery. I had hosted it on Godaddy. So my question is whether I can privately host a website from my home and whether it will be faster to host a website that way than to host via godaddy or network solutions.

Comment: That depends on the connection you have at home. Most likely the answer is that it is not faster though, because of bandwidth available.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy or any other hosting service has its own experts to maintain their server and they have applied many technologies to speed up hosting services and relief their customers headache. Secondly it depends upon the connection and hardware you have at home. After comparing your hardware, software, expertise you have, to those which godaddy has. You will have problems as you are just web developer not expert in other fields required to host a service.
Hope it helps.